# How do you talk to a BerkeleyDB database from Ruby or Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, datamapper, berkeley-db

I have no idea how I would set up a BerkelyDB database in a Ruby or Rails project.

Does anyone have any experience configuring one, that they could talk about?

Maybe using ActiveRecord or Datamapper?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use Moneta, which provides a unified interface for key/value stores:
https://github.com/minad/moneta

Comment: Me too. That's great. Thanks. Btw, I'd like to persist an entity, in case you have any ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992173/how-would-you-represent-a-relational-entity-as-a-single-unit-of-retrievable-data/992223#992223

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use MySQL and use the BerkeleyDB storage engine and use ActiveRecord or DataMapper as usual. Will be cool to use BDB that way.
try this:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bdb-storage-engine.html